# duplicate drop-downs on button click

Tags: javascript, html

Currently I have this setting.
My page loads with 2 drop-downs aligned adjacent and an ADD button.
The ADD button adds a drop-down in the next row using the function addRow().
The function is probably the worst implementation though.

a) I want ADD button to add 2 similar drop-downs aligned adjacent as in the page initially, to the next row. (right now the code only adds 1 drop-down in the next row)

b) is there any way I can put my ADD button to be below the drop-downs I have instead of being next to the first row of drop-downs?

Below is the code

```
<div class="container">
        <table>
                <tr>



<td>
<select id="soflow">
  <!-- This method is nice because it doesn't require extra div tags, but it also doesn't retain the style across all browsers. -->
  <option>Select an Option</option>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
</select>

<select id="soflow">
    <!-- This method is nice because it doesn't require extra div tags, but it also doesn't retain the style across all browsers. -->
    <option>Select an Option</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
  </select>

 <button class = "button" type="button" onClick ="addRow(this)">Add</button></td>

</tr>
</table>

</div>

<script>
    function addRow(btn) {         
        var parentRow = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
        var table = parentRow.parentNode;
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        //var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        var element2 = document.createElement("select");
        element2.setAttribute("id", "soflow")
        //element2.type = "select";
        var option1 = document.createElement("option");
        option1.innerHTML = "Option1";
        option1.value = "1";
        element2.add(option1, null);
        var option2 = document.createElement("option");
        option2.innerHTML = "Option2";
        option2.value = "2";
        element2.add(option2, null);
        cell1.appendChild(element2);
    }
</script>
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give **id** to your `<tr>` to be cloned and to the **table**.   Then use `cloneNode()` to clone the row and append it to the table.

```html
<div class="container">
        <table id="myTable">
                <tr id="initialRow" class="select_row">



<td>
<select id="soflow" class="select1">
  <!-- This method is nice because it doesn't require extra div tags, but it also doesn't retain the style across all browsers. -->
  <option>Select an Option</option>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
</select>

<select id="soflow"  class="select2">
    <!-- This method is nice because it doesn't require extra div tags, but it also doesn't retain the style across all browsers. -->
    <option>Select an Option</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
  </select>

</td>

</tr>
</table>
<button class = "button" type="button" onClick ="addRow()">Add</button>
<button class = "button" type="button" onClick ="getValues()">Print values</button>
</div>

<script>
    const table = document.querySelector('#myTable');
    const rowToDuplicate = document.querySelector('#initialRow');
    function addRow() { 
      var duplicate = rowToDuplicate.cloneNode(true);
   duplicate.removeAttribute('id');      table.appendChild(duplicate);
    }
    
    function getValues() {
      const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.select_row');
     rows.forEach((row, i) => {
       console.log(`row ${i}: select1 `, row.querySelector('.select1').value);   console.log(`row ${i}: select2 `,row.querySelector('.select2').value);
     })
     
    }
</script>
```

Comment: perfect. Can I keep track of all the drop downs created somehow? Because I would need to get the values selected in all the drop downs I add.

Comment: Instead of removing the `id` attribute, You can have a standard pattern for naming it and make it random one, so that one won't conflict with other. Like `duplicate.id = "row_" + Math.random()`.

Comment: Mark it as correct answer, if it answers your question.

Comment: Please have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51575218/javascript-duplicate-multi-level-drop-downs-on-button-click-and-return-values

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for` loop to loop twice and create two `select`s. You should move the button outside of the table if you want it to always be under the selects (both added and initial ones) while adding new rows to the table for the selects.

Also, you can not have more than one element with one `id`. You initially have 2 elements with the `id` "soflow" and are going to add more when the `Add` button is clicked.

To count how many `select`s have been added, you just need a global variable that increase by one each time the `for` loop inside the function is run.

```html
<div class="container">
        <table id="selectTable">
                <tr>



<td>
<select id="soflow">
  <!-- This method is nice because it doesn't require extra div tags, but it also doesn't retain the style across all browsers. -->
  <option>Select an Option</option>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
</select>

<select id="soflow2">
    <!-- This method is nice because it doesn't require extra div tags, but it also doesn't retain the style across all browsers. -->
    <option>Select an Option</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
  </select>
<br/>
 </td>

</tr>
</table>
<button class = "button" type="button" onClick ="addRow(this)">Add</button>
</div>

<script>
    var addedSelects = 0;//total number of dropdowns added
    function addRow(btn) {         
        var table = document.getElementById('selectTable');
        var soflow = document.getElementById("soflow2");
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        table.appendChild(row);
        //var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        row.appendChild(td);
        for(let i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        var element2 = document.createElement("select");
        //element2.setAttribute("id", "soflow"+(i+1))
        //element2.type = "select";
        var option1 = document.createElement("option");
        option1.innerHTML = "Option1";
        option1.value = "1";
        element2.add(option1, null);
        var option2 = document.createElement("option");
        option2.innerHTML = "Option2";
        option2.value = "2";
        element2.add(option2, null);
        td.appendChild(element2);
        addedSelects++;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, but the problem will still be there as he is referring to two select elements with the same ID and the same unwanted behaviour will persist.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. One little thing though. The ADD button should always remain at the bottom i.e. after all drop-downs. It stays fixed at its initial position currently

Comment: @hev1 the new drop downs should be added below the previous ones. This code is adding them next to the previous ones i.e. in the same row.

Comment: @hev1 Thanks! One more thing. Is there a way I can keep track of the all the added drop-downs? Because at the end I need to get all the values currently selected in all drop-downs.

Comment: @nazschi No problem. You can have a global variable that increases by one each time a select is added. I have added such a variable in my code snippet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176949/discussion-between-nazschi-and-hev1).

Answer (score 1):

You have two IDs which have the same name. Change the ID property to have different names for both select elements like `<select id="soflow1"> && <select id="soflow2">` and refer to each element as `soflow1` or `soflow2` in your Javascript. Your JavaScript is referencing two ID elements and causing two dropdowns to open with one call.

IDs should be unique to only one element.

To use the same style across those dropdown elements add a class property which is the same to both select elements like `<select id="soflow1" class="myDropdownClass"> && <select id="soflow2" class="myDropdownClass">` and create CSS for `.myDropdownClass { //some style }`

To put the button underneath the select elements you could do this in your table...

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><select id="soflow1" class="myDropdownClass" ... /></td>
        <td><select id="soflow2" class="myDropdownClass" ... /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><button>text</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to add the event listener to the table since the click will bubble up the dom tree.  Then check to see that it was an element with the class "add" that called the event.  If it is then clone the row node of the table and append it to the table body.  I also placed the button in the table footer so it always stays at the bottom.  Hope this helps.

This method also allows you to change the structure of the table without having to rewrite the javascript to correctly climb the dom tree.  Added a remove row button just for S&G.

In similar fashion to get the values without having ids on every select element you could use the elements index from a list of solflow elements as a unique identifier and the value.

Since you are creating dynamic elements by cloning the row, either the event listeners for the solflow need to be added to the new select elements or the table can handle the change event in which case you add the change handler once and the solflow change bubbles up no matter when the element was added.  In similar fashion a submit button can be created with the table click handler grabbing all the values from the solflow elements in the table and indexing them to the number of solflow elements as either a key value store or as an array of solflow values matching the order in which the elements appear.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class="solflow">
          <option>Select an Option</option>
          <option>Option 1</option>
          <option>Option 2</option>
        </select>
        <select class="solflow">
          <option>Select an Option</option>
          <option>Option 1</option>
          <option>Option 2</option>
        </select>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="button add" type="button">Add</button>
        <button class="button remove" type="button">Remove</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<script>
  function tableClickHandler(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('add')) {
        let tbody = this.querySelector('tbody');
        let row = tbody.querySelector('tr');
        tbody.appendChild( row.cloneNode(true) );
    }
    if (e.target.classList.contains('remove')) {
        var tbody = this.querySelector('tbody');
        var row = tbody.querySelectorAll('tr');
        if (row.length > 1) {
          tbody.removeChild(row[row.length-1]);
        }
    }
  }

  function tableChangeHandler(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('solflow')) {
      let solflows = this.querySelectorAll('.solflow');
      let solflow = e.target;
      let index = -1;
      solflows.forEach(function(el, ind){
        if (el === solflow) { index = ind }
      });
      console.log(index, solflow.value);
    }
  }

  document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('click', tableClickHandler);
  document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('change', tableChangeHandler);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```js
function addRow() {         
    //Select the table
    var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
    //Append a row
    table.innerHTML = table.innerHTML + '<tr>\
        <td>\
            <select>\
                <option>Select an Option</option>\
                <option>Option 1</option>\
                <option>Option 2</option>\
            </select>\
            <select>\
                <option>Select an Option</option>\
                <option>Option 1</option>\
                <option>Option 2</option>\
            </select>\
        </td>\
    </tr>';              
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <!-- This method is nice because it doesn't require extra div tags, but it also doesn't retain the style across all browsers. -->
                    <option>Select an Option</option>
                    <option>Option 1</option>
                    <option>Option 2</option>
                </select>

                <select>
                    <!-- This method is nice because it doesn't require extra div tags, but it also doesn't retain the style across all browsers. -->
                    <option>Select an Option</option>
                    <option>Option 1</option>
                    <option>Option 2</option>
                </select>
            </td>  
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button class = "button" type="button" onClick ="addRow()">Add</button>
</div>
```

The ADD button always stays at the bottom because I moved it out of the table. I removed the id on the select tags, duplicate ids will give you errors, try using `document.getElementsByTagName('select')[x]` selector and use `0` (where `x`) to get the first drop down, `1` to get the second... I also just used text instead of creating the elements via JS because their much easier to read, create, and modify in my opinion. If you have any questions just ask.

Comment: innerHTML is evil ; )