# javascript - duplicate multi-level drop-downs on button click and return values

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the setting. I have two drop-downs adjacent to each other on my initial page. The values in the 2nd drop down depend on the value from the 1st drop down. This works fine.

I have an Add button which duplicates the row of drop-downs i.e. adds 2 adjacent drop-downs below the previous ones.

The addition of drop-downs work fine. However if I have a value selected in my initial drop-down and there is a respective value loaded in 2nd drop-down(dependent on the value from first), that same value is duplicated in the newly added drop-down.

Moreover, the newly added drop-downs are not responsive i.e. a change in left drop-down doesnt change the value in the right drop-down. (The responsiveness is only in the initially added drop-downs)

Maybe I havent used the best javascript practices, forgive me for I am very new at this.

Any feedback is welcomed. Thank you.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="container">
        <table id="myTable">
                <tr id="initialRow" class="select_row">



<td>
        <select  id= "select1" class = "select1">
                <option>Select an option</option>
                <option>yes</option>
                <option>no</option>
              </select>

                <select  id = 'select2' class = "select2">
                </select>

</td>

</tr>
</table>
<button class = "button" type="button" onClick ="addRow()">Add</button>
<button class = "button" type="button" onClick ="getValues()">Print values</button>
</div>

<script>
    const table = document.querySelector('#myTable');
    const rowToDuplicate = document.querySelector('#initialRow');
    function addRow() { 
      var duplicate = rowToDuplicate.cloneNode(true);
   duplicate.removeAttribute('id');      table.appendChild(duplicate);
    }

    function getValues() {
      const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.select_row');
     rows.forEach((row, i) => {
       console.log(`row ${i}: select1 `, row.querySelector('.select1').value);   console.log(`row ${i}: select2 `,row.querySelector('.select2').value);
     })

    }
</script>


<script>
        (function() {

            //setup an object fully of arrays
            //alternativly it could be something like
            //{"yes":[{value:sweet, text:Sweet}.....]}
            //so you could set the label of the option tag something different than the name
            var bOptions = {
              "yes": ["sweet", "wohoo", "yay"],
              "no": ["you suck!", "common son"]
            };

            var A = document.getElementById('select1');
            var B = document.getElementById('select2');

            //on change is a good event for this because you are guarenteed the value is different
            A.onchange = function() {
              //clear out B
              B.length = 0;
              //get the selected value from A
              var _val = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
              //loop through bOption at the selected value
              for (var i in bOptions[_val]) {
                //create option tag
                var op = document.createElement('option');
                //set its value
                op.value = bOptions[_val][i];
                //set the display label
                op.text = bOptions[_val][i];
                //append it to B
                B.appendChild(op);
              }
            };
            //fire this to update B on load
            A.onchange();

          })();
      </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things:

1. The code in the script tag runs once. That means that you init your selects once. Those selects you add dynamically are not initialized and do not react on the `onchange` event.
2. Your clone was not sufficient. You need to clone the `clean` row and then keep cloning that.
3. You depend too much on the `ids`. Once you start dealing with the new dynamic rows those ids are a pain.

I did a quick fix that should get you going. Let me know if this helps.

```html
<div class="container">
  <table id="myTable">
    <tr id="initialRow" class="select_row">
      <td>
        <select class="select1">
          <option>Select an option</option>
          <option>yes</option>
          <option>no</option>
        </select>
        <select class="select2"></select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button class="button" type="button" onClick="addRow()">Add</button>
  <button class="button" type="button" onClick="getValues()">Print values</button>
</div>

<script>
  const table = document.getElementById('myTable');
 const initialRow = document.getElementById('initialRow');
  const rowToDuplicate = initialRow.cloneNode(true);

  function addRow() {
     let duplicate = rowToDuplicate.cloneNode(true); 
     let select1 = duplicate.lastElementChild.firstElementChild
     let select2 = duplicate.lastElementChild.lastElementChild  

     select1.setAttribute('id', 'select1-' + table.children.length)
     select2.setAttribute('id', 'select2-' + table.children.length)

     table.appendChild(duplicate);
     initSelects(select1, select2);
  }

  function getValues() {
    const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.select_row');
    rows.forEach((row, i) => {
      console.log(`row ${i}: select1 `, row.querySelector('.select1').value);
      console.log(`row ${i}: select2 `, row.querySelector('.select2').value);
    })
  }
 
 function initSelects(a, b) {
  var bOptions = {
      "yes": ["sweet", "wohoo", "yay"],
      "no": ["you suck!", "common son"]
    };

  a.onchange = function () {
   //clear out B
   b.length = 0;
   //get the selected value from A
   var _val = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
   //loop through bOption at the selected value
   for (var i in bOptions[_val]) {
    //create option tag
    var op = document.createElement('option');
    //set its value
    op.value = bOptions[_val][i];
    //set the display label
    op.text = bOptions[_val][i];
    //append it to B
    b.appendChild(op);
    }
  }
 }
 
 initSelects(
  initialRow.lastElementChild.firstElementChild, 
  initialRow.lastElementChild.lastElementChild
 );
</script>
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you!

Comment: Added the `ids` as you ware asking